# grep for a substring

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a file that has the following user names in random places in the file:

```
albert@ghhdh
albert@jdfjgjjg
john@jfkfeie
mike@fjfkjf
bill@fjfj
bill@fkfkfk
```

Usernames are the names to the left of the @ symbol.
I want to use unix commands to grep the file  for usernames, then make a count of unique usernames.

Therefore using the example above, the output should state that there are 4 unique users (I just need the count as the output, no words)

Can someone help me determine the correct count?

Comment: What does the file look like exactly? Are there words other than email addresses? Are the email addresses always at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the words before `@`, sort them and count them :

```
cat test.txt | cut -d '@' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c
```

With `test.txt` :

```
albert@ghhdh
john@jfkfeie
bill@fjfj
mike@fjfkjf
bill@fkfkfk
albert@jdfjgjjg
```

It outputs :

```
  2 albert
  2 bill
  1 john
  1 mike
```

Note that the duplicate usernames don't have to be grouped in the input list.

If you're just interested in the count of uniq users :

```
cat test.txt | cut -d '@' -f 1 | sort -u | wc -l
# => 4
```

Or shorter :

```
cut -d '@' -f 1 test.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Close, add "| wc -l" and it returns 4, that is the amount of uniq users that he searched for

Comment: Don't we have here a useless use of cat?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: Not that stupid argument again. UNIX is all about chaining commands together, who cares if we use n or n+1? I find `cat | cut` more readable because the information flow is clear : `test.txt` would be in the middle otherwise. It's also easier to adapt to other inputs. I updated the answer anyway.

Comment: Every pipe is a different subshell. One more pipe is one more subshell used , especially without a reason in case of cat. All the new guys are getting frustrated for using endless pipes without a reason. If you can do the job with two commands instead of four, the job will be done faster. Are all these just a matter of appearance?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I agree for the theory. In practice though, I don't care about a few milliseconds more (if anything) in the shell. A nice information flow is more important to me.

Comment: On the same terms , i would agree that if the file under process is small , we talk only about some milliseconds. But in big files, the impact of an extra pipe can be important.

Comment: OP said the usernames are scattered all over the file. `cut -d@ -f`` will grab more than just the username in that case.  So, this solution won't work unless usernames are right at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @codeforester: You probably have a point, I didn't understand the question that way. Your solution is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that finds the usernames anywhere on the line (not just at the beginning), even if there are multiple usernames on a single line, and finds their unique count:

```
grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_.]*@' file | cut -f1 -d@ | sort -u | wc -l
```

- `-o` only fetches the matched portion
- `-E` processes extended regex
- `\b[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]]*@` matches usernames (a string following a word boundary `\b` that starts with an alpha or underscore followed by zero or more alphanumeric and other permitted characters, ending with a `@`
- `cut -f1 -d@` extracts the username portion which is then sorted and counted for unique names

Answer (score 0):

Faster with one awk command, if awk is allowed:

```
awk -F"@" '!seen[$1]++{c++}END{print "Unique users =" c}'
```

Small Explanation:
using @ as delimiter (-F) you look for field 1 = $1 for awk.
For every field 1 that is not seen again we increase a counter c.
In the same time we increase the particular field1 so if found again the test "not seen" will not be valid.
At the end we just print the counter of unique "seen".

As a plus, this solution does not require pre-sorting. Duplicates would be found even if file is not sorted.

Comment: I'd argue that readability is much more important than using one `cat` too much.